# How to make card reader work without restarting the system?

Tags: macos, usb, keychain, cardreader, id-card

I live in Estonia where citizens, e-residents etc can use their ID card to prove identity by signing documents, open encrypted files that are intended for a specific individual and so on.

For that purpose we here use card readers (of course).

The problem is, unlike USB mice, USB keyboards and such things, to get it work I need first to restart my Mac. In other cases keychain won't see this device and I won't be able to do anything with it.

Is there a way to make my ID card work and seen by keychain without restarting my machine every time I want to use it?

Maybe there's a way to somehow restart just keychain or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, that was easy enough.

If somebody experiences kind of same issue, just reset NVRAM and SMC.